# Scoped Storage - File URI shared with other app is null

Tags: android, uri, android-fileprovider, scoped-storage

I am having a problem where I am trying to share a file from one app to another via scoped storage. For some reason App A is trying to send the URI of a file to App B. However, the URI received by App B returns null.  Here is my code for sending the file:

```
String filename = ".bisym";
String fullPath;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q || Environment.isExternalStorageLegacy()) {
    fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "bisym/" + filename;
} else {
    fullPath = new File(getFilesDir(), "bisym_dir").getPath();
}
try {
    File file = new File( fullPath );
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.octal.provider", file);

    String apkPackage = "com.mobilityresearch.treadmill3";
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(apkPackage);

    if ( intent == null ) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, could not get launch intent for: " + apkPackage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

    context.startActivity(intent);
}
catch ( IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(context, "IllegalArgumentException: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch ( Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
     Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Here is my code for receiving the intent from App B:

```
//called from onNewIntent and onCreate
public void processBiSymData() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Uri uri = (Uri)bundle.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM); //returns null
    
    mApp.getBiSymDeviceAddr(uri);
}
```

For some reason, I am getting `null` for the URI App B. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: `getIntent()` would return the `Intent` used to create the activity. If the activity was already running, and a fresh `Intent` is being delivered to it, you get that `Intent` by overriding `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: So how would I correctly receive the URI being sent from App A when App B is freshly started?

Comment: The receiving side there in theory would be fine. Since a launcher activity does not use MIME types, I can't see how your first code snippet actually works.

Comment: I am trying to share a plain text file from App A to App B.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Your initial code snippet is confusing, with two `startActivity()` calls. Perhaps you should only have one `startActivity()` call.

Comment: I removed the second startActivity, still returning null.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I am trying to receive the intent from the wrong activity.